# Google script to forward email to recipient

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

While creating a rule in google admin I accidentally made a mistake and all the emails in my enterprise where sent to a specific email account. The emails skipped the inbox of the actual recipient and were sent to a global inbox.
Is there a script I can write to undo this meaning forwarding the email to the user who were suppose to receive this.

Comment: You can use the GAM Tool to delete that particular message from the user's inbox who have accidentally received the email.

Comment: It was just one account who received all the email and I do not want to delete it but send the emails to the intended recipients.